# Mesh with constraints

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh

Is it possible to construct a constrained tetrahedral mesh of a domain using Tetgen or similar software? What I mean by constrained is that there are some nodes or edges that are not free but are predefined by the user.

Comment: Yes, all unstructured mesh generators (that are worth using) can generate constrained delaunay triangulations in 2d or 3d. I personally do not have experience with tetgen, but i have used gmsh successfully for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've used tetgen to do precisely this.

If you're filling a surface mesh, you'll have to generate facet triangulations first. Then you can decide whether or not you want a constrained or conforming tetrahedral mesh.

The result of either choice is described in better detail within [the manual](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/1.5/doc/manual/manual002.html).